How To Combine/Convert/Package Frontend (Nextjs, TypeScript) And Backend (Golang, Echo, Postgresql) Web Application Into Desktop Application
I have 2 repositories for a web application project, one for the frontend ui and one for the backend api. The frontend was created using NextJS Typescript, while the backend was created using Golang Echo with a PostgreSQL database. How do I combine them or convert them or package them into a desktop application so that users can install it on their desktop locally and can run my application without using the internet? or perhaps more precisely, is this even possible? or is it better for me to develop it from scratch for the desktop version?

Take a look at : wails.io

I've done it, but it's still quite difficult for me, because the documentation is incomplete in my opinion, can you show me a more complete source than the official documentation? or a video? or a sample project that is similar to my case?

You will not be able to embed Postgres, to begin with. I'd suggest using a docker compose for providing test|staging-environments. For air gapped environments, you can export the according images. If you want to make it extra-fancy, you can create a container including all the resources required, writing them to a bind out if run.
